# Issues & Errors with Restore from ios7 Backup to ios9 on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, data-synchronization, restore

**Steps & Insights:**

- `iPhone 5 GSM` - `iOS 7.1.1`- 64 GB
- `Backup` using `iTunes 12.3.0.4` on `Windows 8.1 Pro`
- `Shift + Restore` the Apple Firmware `iOS 9.0.2` `.ipsw` file into iPhone via `DFU mode`
- Setup as `New` - `iPhone iOS 9.0.2`
- After bit of play, `iOS 9.0.2` felt stable, so I tried to `Restore` from my `iOS 7.1.1 Backup`
- Left to do what it wants: iTunes took 10+ maybe 15 hours to finish Restore + auto App Sync after restore

### **Problems:**

**During the iPhone Restore from Backup:**

iTunes auto created multiple backups for some reason - Which Backup to use for restore now?

- iTunes auto created multiple backups, and as restore failed once, due to lack of extra drive space for the additional instance/ copy of Backup. {I had 30 GB open but iTunes filled it all up}

  - So I "cloned" my SSD to a bigger HDD to do this and my Restore went through after 10/15 hours, with some caveats:
  - Bunch of Apps would not restore i.e. could not be sync'ed back to iPhone due to Error that was like (0xBE00000E or 0xBE00000E). Googling it nothing came up

### Which Backup to use for restore now?

---

**After the iPhone Restore from Backup:**

Sync is stuck for several Apps that are in "Waiting" "Will Install" state as outlined in this split question.

[Restore from Backup: Apps in iTunes library were not installed on iPhone because Unknown Error occurred 0xE800002D](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213205/restore-from-backup-causes-message-apps-in-your-itunes-library-were-not-install)

### How to Resolve stuck "waiting" "Will Install" Apps?

---

### Additional Details on Backups & its Copies:

**New Backup folders are identical to original Backup except for the following:**

- Owner permissions are different; I did try & use "Run as Admin on iTunes"
- 1 file in both folders `info.plist` is different, with further tinkering found to contain identical data in XML vs Binary formats, except for 2 small strings:

  - 1:30 | 32 MB | plist XML
    -- `<string>AS_iPhone5_711</string>`
    -- `<string>01b4384a905a10b3061004b3281a915aca60c362</string>`
  - 4:30 | 22 MB | plist Binary, 99% Identical when converted to XML using `putil`
    -- `<string>AS_iPhone5_711 - Oct 23, 2015, 4:06 AM</string>`
    -- `<string>01b4384a905a10b3061004b3281a915aca60c362-20151023-040611</string>`

---

**Screenshots of Backups Folder with Timestamps & Comparisons (using Beyond Compare):**
*Images will not show clearly until you click to Zoom in.*

`C:\Users\..MyUserName..\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`
[image: Backup Folders, Auto created Backups & Timestamps]

[image: Backups as shown in iTunes Device Preferences]

Answer (score 1):

When you see two backups for the iPhone, there is one automatically from sync and one you did by hand by "Backup Now". I would choose that one, it is the one marked with the precise date.
Note: auto backups (sync) are overwriting the earlier one.

Comment: Notice the Folder marked 1:30 AM {made by me} vs 4:30 AM. On disk they show different timings, but in iTunes its a "new name that includes 4:00 am" but time stamped for same time: 1:30 am. Funky. 

I will post back more once I dissect `info.plist` comparison.

Comment: The second time I did a restore from the same backup it created another copy. 3rd time I did it it created another. What is wrong with iTunes?